# What are the differences between mountpoint=legacy and mountpoint=none for ZFS datasets?

Tags: linux, zfs, zfsonlinux

I have noted that some tutorials (ex.: [Arch Linux Root on ZFS](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Getting%20Started/Arch%20Linux/Root%20on%20ZFS.html)) use `mountpoint=legacy` while others (ex.: [Install Arch Linux on ZFS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Install_Arch_Linux_on_ZFS)) use `mountpoint=none` for what the datasets used as a containers for separation of system data and user data (`/home`).

They are exchangeable and haven't noticed any difference on a system running with either of that.

What are the differences (if any at all) between the two options?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a ZFS legacy mount point?](https://superuser.com/questions/790036/what-is-a-zfs-legacy-mount-point)

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR:

Both prevents the dataset to be mounted, but mount management is different :

- by the OS : `mountpoint=legacy`  (`/etc/fstab`, `/etc/vfstab`, …)
- by ZFS : `mountpoint=none` (used in a container set-up)

For further details, please take a look to the ZFS documentation, on the [property](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/man/master/7/zfsprops.7.html#Mount_Points) or the [concept section](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/man/master/7/zfsconcepts.7.html#Mount_Points):

> #### Mount Points
>
> (…)
>
> A file system can also have a mount point set in the mountpoint property. This directory is created as needed, and ZFS automatically mounts the file system when the zfs mount -a command is invoked (without editing /etc/fstab). The mountpoint property can be inherited, so if pool/home has a mount point of /export/stuff, then pool/home/user automatically inherits a mount point of /export/stuff/user.
>
> A file system mountpoint property of none prevents the file system from being mounted.
>
> If needed, ZFS file systems can also be managed with traditional tools (mount, umount, /etc/fstab). If a file system's mount point is set to legacy, ZFS makes no attempt to manage the file system, and the administrator is responsible for mounting and unmounting the file system. Because pools must be imported before a legacy mount can succeed, administrators should ensure that legacy mounts are only attempted after the zpool import process finishes at boot time. For example, on machines using systemd, the mount option
>
> (…)